# std::function inside template class giving object creation error

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Getting below error for the code given below. Trying to have 3 std::function inside an template class and then initialize them with different functions from different classes.

Why is this error happening? What's wrong with below code?

[image]

```
template <typename T>
class CFuntion {
public:
    std::function<void()> callback_1;
    std::function<void()> callback_2;
    std::function<void()> callback_3;

    template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
    CFuntion(A cb1, B cb2, C cb3)
        : callback_1(cb1), callback_2(cb2), callback_3(cb3)
    { }
};

class Impl1 {
public:
    void do_something1() {
        cout << "Inside Impl1 do_something1" << endl;
    }

    void do_something2() {
        cout << "Inside Impl1 do_something2" << endl;
    }
};

class Impl2 {
public:
    void do_something1() {
        cout << "Inside Impl2 do_something1" << endl;
    }

    void do_something2() {
        cout << "Inside Impl2 do_something2" << endl;
    }
};

class Impl3 {
public:
    void do_something1() {
        cout << "Inside Impl3 do_something1" << endl;
    }

    void do_something2() {
        cout << "Inside Impl3 do_something2" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<CFuntion<void>> ptr1 = make_unique<CFuntion<void>>(std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1, &Impl2::do_something1, 
                                        &Impl3::do_something2));
    ptr1->callback_1();
    ptr1->callback_2();
    ptr1->callback_3();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CFunction<void>` has two constructors - a constructor you provided that takes three arguments, and a copy constructor that takes `const CFunction<void>&`. You are trying to pass a single argument that's a bind expression, `std::bind(x, y, z)`. None of the constructors can take that argument.

Comment: In addition, your bind expression doesn't make any sense: you ask it to call `Impl1::do_something1` with two arguments, `&Impl2::do_something1` and `&Impl3::do_something2`. You probably meant three separate `bind` calls. But simple `std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1)` won't work either - `do_something1` is a non-static member function and requires an instance of `Impl1` to be called on. All in all, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - i also tried with this code but that too fails, unique_ptr<CFuntion<void>> ptr1 = make_unique<CFuntion<void>>(std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1), std::bind(&Impl2::do_something1),
        std::bind(&Impl3::do_something2));

Comment: My second comment addresses that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part:

```cpp
unique_ptr<CFuntion<void>> ptr1 = make_unique<CFuntion<void>(std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1, &Impl2::do_something1, &Impl3::do_something2));
//                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, you pass only one object to your `CFunction<void>`'s constructor. What you needed might be this:

```cpp
// You need to pass temporary objects to 'std::bind()' to bind non-static member functions
Impl1 obj1;
Impl2 obj2;
Impl3 obj3;
std::unique_ptr<CFuntion<void>> ptr1 = std::make_unique<CFuntion<void>>(std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1, obj1), std::bind(&Impl2::do_something1, obj2), std::bind(&Impl3::do_something2, obj3));
```

Or, by looking at your `Impl1`, `Impl2` and `Impl3` classes it seems you could just make their member methods `static` (As none of those three classes seem to need any sort of distinction between their objects or have any instance variables to access/modify.):

```cpp
class Impl1 {
public:
    static void do_something1() {
        cout << "Inside Impl1 do_something1" << endl;
    }

    static void do_something2() {
        cout << "Inside Impl1 do_something2" << endl;
    }
};

class Impl2 {
public:
    static void do_something1() {
        cout << "Inside Impl2 do_something1" << endl;
    }

    static void do_something2() {
        cout << "Inside Impl2 do_something2" << endl;
    }
};

class Impl3 {
public:
    static void do_something1() {
        cout << "Inside Impl3 do_something1" << endl;
    }

    static void do_something2() {
        cout << "Inside Impl3 do_something2" << endl;
    }
};
```

That way, you just need to do this, which appears to be what you want to do:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<CFuntion<void>> ptr1 = std::make_unique<CFuntion<void>>(std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1), std::bind(&Impl2::do_something1), std::bind(&Impl3::do_something2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question though, if i need to pass arguments to do_something functions, how can that be done?

Comment: You can put the argument values in `std::bind`, `std::bind(&Impl1::do_something1, 12, "abc", 'a')`, etc. Also, the [cppreference page of `std::bind()` might be useful for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).